# Python Functions in Classes NameError

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-class

I created a class that has different functions that output different graphs. One of the function is to calculate the bid width for whatever variable is being passed. Last night my notebook was running wonderfully but now I'm getting NameError: name 'bin_width' is not defined and I'm not sure why. I tested the bin function in a separate notebook and it works but for some reason it's not working in the class.

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-1bce9e9c118e> in <module>
      2 histo = Graphs('YRONJOB', None, None, None)
      3 #Call histogram() function to apply to object
----> 4 histo.histogram()

<ipython-input-46-02e598bef21f> in histogram(self)
     42 
     43         #Create variable that we call the function to calculate the bin width
---> 44         bin = bin_width(self.A)
     45         print(bin)
     46 

NameError: name 'bin_width' is not defined
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the issue. Below I attached my import cell, the first four functions of my class, and the cell where I created the object.

```
#Import library
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Automatically creates a dataframe don't need pd.DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/tianachargin/Desktop/PythonSG/STAT 4490/WidgeOne_CSV.csv")
#print out dataset
print(data)

class Graphs: 
#Constructor with parameters
    #Self isn't a pass by value parameter but it allows you to reference
    def __init__(self, quantVar1, quantVar2, qualVar1, qualVar2):   
        self.A = quantVar1   #First quantitative variable           
        self.B = quantVar2   #Second quantitative variable
        self.C = qualVar1    #First qualitative variable
        self.D = qualVar2    #Second qualitative variable 
        
#Function that calculates bin width for the histogram 
    def bin_width(variable):
        #Import libaray
        import math
        
        #Create variable to create array for bins
        #Find min of column
        min = data[variable].min()
        #Find max of column
        max = data[variable].max()
        #Find the the count of rows (number of data/size/n)
        index = data.index
        number_of_rows = len(index) 
        #Calculate number of bins and round up
        num_of_bins = (math.ceil(math.sqrt(number_of_rows)))
        #Calculate bin width (max - min)/# of bins
        bin_width = ((max - min)/num_of_bins)
        #Round bin width to one decimal place
        increment_bin = round(bin_width, 1)
        #Start bin 
        start_bin = (min - increment_bin)
        #End bin
        end_bin = (max + increment_bin)
        
        return start_bin, end_bin, increment_bin
        
#Histogram Function 
    def histogram(self):
        #Import libraries
        import math
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
        #Create variable that we call the function to calculate the bin width
        bin = bin_width(self.A) 
         
        #Start at value = bin[0], Stop at value = bin[1], Increment by value of bin[2]
        bins = np.array(np.arange(start = bin[0], stop = bin[1], step = bin[2]))
        #Histogram function
        plt.hist(data[self.A], bins, label = self.A, color = "red")
        #x-axis label
        plt.xlabel(self.A, fontsize = 16)  
        #y-axis lable
        plt.ylabel("Frequency of " + self.A, fontsize = 16)
        #Title of graph
        plt.title("Histogram of " + self.A, loc = 'center')
        plt.show()
        return


#Stacked Histogram Function  
    def stacked_histogram(self):
        #Import libraries
        import numpy as np
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        
        #Create combonations of the values for the two options
        data[self.C + "-" + self.D] = data[self.C] + " " + data[self.D] 
        combos = np.unique(data[self.C + "-" + self.D])
        #Create variable that we call the function to calculate the bin width
        bin = bin_width(self.A)
        #Start at value = bin[0], Stop at value = bin[1], Increment by value of bin[2]
        bins = np.array(np.arange(start = bin[0], stop = bin[1], step = bin[2]))
        
        #Create histogram
        for i in range(len(combos)):
           plt.hist(data[data[self.C + "-" + self.D].isin(combos[i:(len(combos))])][self.A], bins, label = combos[i:(len(combos))])
        #x-axis label
        plt.xlabel(self.A, fontsize = 16) 
        #y-axis lable
        plt.ylabel("Frequency of ", fontsize = 16)
        #Legend of graph
        plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
        #Title of graph
        plt.title("Histogram of " + self.A + " with unique combinations of " + self.D + " and " + self.C, loc = 'center')
        plt.show()
        return
    

#Overlapping Histogram Function 
    def overlap_histogram(self):
        #Import libraries
        import numpy as np
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        
        #Create variable that we call the function to calculate the bin width
        bin = bin_width(self.A)
        
        #Start at value = bin[0], Stop at value = bin[1], Increment by value of bin[2]
        bins = np.array(np.arange(start = bin[0], stop = bin[1], step = bin[2]))
        #Create histogram
        plt.hist(data[self.A], bins, alpha = 0.5, label = self.A, color = "red")
        plt.hist(data[self.B], bins, alpha = 0.5, label = self.B, color = "blue")
        #x-axis label
        plt.xlabel("Variables", fontsize = 16)  
        #y-axis lable
        plt.ylabel("Frequency", fontsize = 16)
        #Legend of graph
        plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
        #Title of graph
        plt.title("Overlapping Histogram of Variables " + self.A + " and " + self.B, loc = 'center')
        plt.show()

#Create an object from class Graphs that will have one parameter
histo = Graphs('YRONJOB', None, None, None)
#Call histogram() function to apply to object
histo.histogram()
```

Comment: Putting style aside, the definition of `bin_width` is missing `self` as an argument and it should be called with `self.bin_width`. Also, you do not want to use `bin`, `min` and `max` as variable names as they hide the built-ins with the same names

Comment: And you are also using `bin_width` as a variable name **inside** the `bin_width` method. This should also be avoided

Comment: And as a side note, you do not need all the import statements inside every method. It's enough to have them at the top on the module-level

Comment: Is this update of the function correct? 
    def bin_width(self):
        import math
        min = data[self.A].min()
        max = data[self.A].max()
        index = data.index
        number_of_rows = len(index) 
        num_of_bins = (math.ceil(math.sqrt(number_of_rows)))
        bin_size = ((max - min)/num_of_bins)
        increment_bin = round(bin_size, 1)
        start_bin = (min - increment_bin)
        end_bin = (max + increment_bin)
        return start_bin, end_bin, increment_bin

Comment: Do not add code in the comments. Also, why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, the issues were that I should have passed self as an argument to the function and then I was calling the function wrong.

Answer (score -2):

first thing i want to say is that youre not supposed to import modules in functions. its enough to import them on the top.
Second thing, youre doing

def bin_width(variable)

and using like this

bin_width(self.A)

right way
def bin_width(self, variable)

usage:

bin = bin_width(self, yourvariable)

Comment: What do you mean modules within functions? Can I not call a function within a function in python? self.A is the reference to the variable I shouldn't have a comma between them, right?

Comment: you missed the self assignment while made the function and when calling